# How to continue an absolute positioned column background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following problem. I have a Bootstrap 3 website where is a section with `.col-md-8` (relative) and `.col-md-4` (absolute). 
In my `col-md-4` I have another div with absolute positioning (`.hf--container`).
This block should be 100% width, but I need to have left: -27px there, so there's an empty space after this div. How can I get rid of this space?

I've attached an image just in case.
[image]
Thanks!

```css
.home--hero {
    background: #333;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    margin-top: 188px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.hero-form {
    background: rgba(121,121,121,0.4);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 36%;
}
.hf--container {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -27px;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
    padding-left: 42px;
}
.hf--container:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -13px;
    left: 0;
    border-bottom: 13px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    border-left: 27px solid transparent;
}
.hf--container--alt {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
}
h3.demo {
    color: #0db20d;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 23px;
    margin-top: 22px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.register-block {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 316px;
}
.form-control--home {
    background: #d3d3d3;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 4px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 4px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 4px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 37px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
    font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
    color: #000;
}
.form-control--home.alt {
    padding-left: 3px;
}
.hero-form .form-field {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.hero-form #privacy_box {
    padding-bottom: 16px;
}
.hero-form #privacy_box label {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
.hero-form #privacy_box label.option a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.home--hero h1 {
    font-size: 25px;
}
.home--hero ul {
    padding-left: 7px;
}
.home--hero ul li {
    color: #474747;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 23px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 2px 0 8px 13px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.home--hero ul li:before {
    color: #474747;
    font-size: 18px;
    content: "✓";
    font-weight: 622;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin-left: -20px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
.hero--wrapper {
    padding-left: 39px;
    padding-top: 157px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="home--hero">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-container">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 npl">
                    <div class="hero--wrapper">
                        <h1>Trading website</h1>
                        <ul class="banner-list banner-list-black">
                            <li><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></li>
                            <li><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></li>
                            <li><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></li>
                            <li><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></li>
                            <li><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></li>
                            <li><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></li>
                        </ul>    
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 npl npr hero-form">
                    <div class="hf--container">
                        <div class="register-block">
                            <h3 class="demo">Demo-Account now</h3>
                            <form id="demo_eng" method="post" class="demo-account" action="#">
                            <div class="col-md-12 npl npr">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-field">
                                    <input name="fname" type="text" class="form-control form-control--home" id="first_name" value="" placeholder="First Name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-field">
                                    <input name="lname" type="text" class="form-control form-control--home" id="last_name" value="" placeholder="Last Name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-field">
                                    <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control form-control--home" placeholder="Email" id="real_email" value="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div id="privacy_box">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox required" value="1" name="privacy" id="privacy">  
                                        <label for="privacy" class="option" id="privacy_label">
                                        <a target="_blank" style="font-size:12px;" href="/pdf/LFS-Privacy-Policy.pdf">Privacy accepted</a> 
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="language" value="en">
                                    <input type="submit" name="quick_submit" id="quick_submit" value="Free Demo Account" class="btn btn-fill btn-block btn-success btn-reg">
                                    <p>Disclaimer</p>
                                </div><!-- 12: buttons -->
                            </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- content -->
        </div><!-- row -->
    </div><!-- container -->
</section><!-- home hero section -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to add `width: 100%` to your container.

Here:

```css
.home--hero {
    background: #333;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    margin-top: 188px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.hero-form {
    background: rgba(121,121,121,0.4);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 36%;
}
.hf--container {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    position: absolute;
    left: -27px;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
    padding-left: 42px;
}
.hf--container:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -13px;
    left: 0;
    border-bottom: 13px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    border-left: 27px solid transparent;
}
.hf--container--alt {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
}
h3.demo {
    color: #0db20d;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 23px;
    margin-top: 22px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.register-block {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 316px;
}
.form-control--home {
    background: #d3d3d3;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 4px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 4px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 4px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 37px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
    font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
    color: #000;
}
.form-control--home.alt {
    padding-left: 3px;
}
.hero-form .form-field {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.hero-form #privacy_box {
    padding-bottom: 16px;
}
.hero-form #privacy_box label {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
.hero-form #privacy_box label.option a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.home--hero h1 {
    font-size: 25px;
}
.home--hero ul {
    padding-left: 7px;
}
.home--hero ul li {
    color: #474747;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 23px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 2px 0 8px 13px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.home--hero ul li:before {
    color: #474747;
    font-size: 18px;
    content: "✓";
    font-weight: 622;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin-left: -20px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
.hero--wrapper {
    padding-left: 39px;
    padding-top: 157px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="home--hero">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-container">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 npl">
                    <div class="hero--wrapper">
                        <h1>Trading website</h1>
                        <ul class="banner-list banner-list-black">
                            <li><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></li>
                            <li><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></li>
                            <li><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></li>
                            <li><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></li>
                            <li><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></li>
                            <li><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></li>
                        </ul>    
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 npl npr hero-form">
                    <div class="hf--container">
                        <div class="register-block">
                            <h3 class="demo">Demo-Account now</h3>
                            <form id="demo_eng" method="post" class="demo-account" action="#">
                            <div class="col-md-12 npl npr">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-field">
                                    <input name="fname" type="text" class="form-control form-control--home" id="first_name" value="" placeholder="First Name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-field">
                                    <input name="lname" type="text" class="form-control form-control--home" id="last_name" value="" placeholder="Last Name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-field">
                                    <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control form-control--home" placeholder="Email" id="real_email" value="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div id="privacy_box">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox required" value="1" name="privacy" id="privacy">  
                                        <label for="privacy" class="option" id="privacy_label">
                                        <a target="_blank" style="font-size:12px;" href="/pdf/LFS-Privacy-Policy.pdf">Privacy accepted</a> 
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="language" value="en">
                                    <input type="submit" name="quick_submit" id="quick_submit" value="Free Demo Account" class="btn btn-fill btn-block btn-success btn-reg">
                                    <p>Disclaimer</p>
                                </div><!-- 12: buttons -->
                            </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- content -->
        </div><!-- row -->
    </div><!-- container -->
</section><!-- home hero section -->
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this case the background is only around the current content (.register-block), but I need the 100% width background :(